# creating a sorted list in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So basically I have a table named `contents` where users can store their items. Normally here when a user add a new item, The item is added at the end of rows.

Something like:

```
|ID | Name | Item  |
--------------------
|1 | Jack  | pen   |
|2 | Mark  | apple |
|3 | albert| orange|
|4 | Jack  | pencil|
```

But the problem with above is that it might take a lot of time when we have a lot of users and items like Jack's first item is at row ID 40 and item #2 is at 1000048 and so which might take a while to search for all the items that belongs to Jack So I was wondering how to sort them up by their Name so it could be something like:

```
|ID | Name | Item  |
--------------------
|1 | Jack  | pen   |
|2 | Jack  | pencil|
|3 | Mark  | apple |
|4 | albert| orange|
```

And if the user added a new item it should be added to the end of his rows list.

All replies are much appreciated, Thank:)

Comment: Not sure of understand... you want a sql with a simple "order by" clause but the problem is it takes too much time because your table is very large, right? maybe you must create an index: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Yes Table is very large, that is why I need a faster way to search for them

Comment: Your database structure needs to be improved. You haven't modeled your DB properly, and I think you should start by do a re-model and applying Normal Forms to it. After all of that you can think about creating Indexes on the columns that will be in the search conditions.

Comment: I do need to change the structure of course but can you tell me how to restructure it with a new faster design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add index(es) for any column (or combination of columns) you want to *search* for and/or want to *order by*.

Do *not* reorder the table, nor re-number the ids.

If you are talking about 1000 rows, you are unlikely to notice any performance problems even if you don't do proper indexing or normalization.  With a million rows, you will notice.